# Prevent git submodule update from deleting submodule committed changes

Tags: git, git-submodules

This seems a to be a common issue, but i just can't find a reasonable solution:
IMHO, the worse problem with [git submodules](http://schacon.github.com/git/user-manual.html#submodules) is where submodule committed but not pushed changes are easily deleted with the containing repository usage of `git submodule update`. Quoting:

> It’s not safe to run git submodule update if you’ve made and committed
>   changes within a submodule without checking out a branch first. They
>   will be silently overwritten:

(...followed by an example there).

So, to the question-
Let `super` be a repository root folder and `submod` be a child folder containing a submodule:

```
-super   
     -submod
```

When i commit in the submodule but not push, and then run `git submodule update` i get my *committed* changes in submod **deleted** (oh, the horror).
How can i add a confirmation `are you sure` question when i'm doing this?
hooks, scripts or any other applicable ideas are more the welcome.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no hook for pre-submodule-update, so what you'd probably need to do is instead write a script that you use *instead* of `git submodule update`.

A simple way to see if you have any modified submodules is this:

```
if git submodule status | grep -q '^+'; then
    # at least one submodule has changes
fi
```

Also note that if an accidental update blows away your changes, you might still be able to salvage them via the submodule checkout's reflog (since submodule checkouts are effectively full Git repositories in their own right).